# How to speed up the Nifi streaming logs to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm new to `nifi`, trying to read files and push to `kafka`. From some basic reading, I'm able to do that with the following.[image]

With this flow I'm able to achieve 0.5million records/sec, of size 100kb each. I would like to catch-up to the speed of 2millions/sec. Data from `ListFile` and `FetchFile` processors through `slitText` processors is great. But, getting settled at `PublishKafka`.

So clearly bottleneck is with the PublishKafka. How do I improve this performance? Should I tune something at Kafka end or with Nifi-PublishKafka end.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: where is a bottleneck in your flow ?

Comment: @daggett well, that's the point i would like to know. Something to do with splits or publishKafka?

Comment: provide a high load to your flow and check queues between processors. where a larger amount of files/bytes are queued then the target processor is a bottleneck.

Comment: @daggett I have done some test. Updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Record Oriented` processors i.e **`PublishKafkaRecord_1.0`** processor.

So that your **flow** will be:

```
1.ListFile
2.FetchFile
3.PublishKafkaRecord_1.0 //Configure with more than one concurrent task
```

By using this flow we are not going to use `SplitText` processors and Define `RecordReader/Writer` controller services in `PublishKafkaRecord` processor.

*`In addition`*
you can also distribute the load by using **`Remote Process Groups`**

***Flow:***

```
1.ListFile
2.RemoteProcessGroup
3.FetchFile
4.PublishKafkaRecord_1.0 //In scheduling tab keep more than one concurrent task
```

Refer to [this](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/) link for more details regards to design/configuring the above flow.

Starting from NiFi-1.8 version we **don't** need to use **`RemoteProcessGroup`** (to distribute the load) as we can configure Connections(relationships) to distribute the load balancing.

Refer to [this](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster) and [NiFi-5516](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5516) links for more details regards to these `new additions` in NiFi-1.8 version.

Comment: That's great info. Testing this out, would post my update. Thanks

Comment: I don't see a difference by introducring RemoteProcessGroup. How different is ListFiles->FetchFiles->Kafka from ListFiles->RemoteProcessGroup->FetchFiles-> Kakfa, when FetchFiles and ListFiles are configured as allnodes instead of primary?

Comment: @srikanth, 1. You need to run all **`List`** processors on **`Primary node only`**, now all flowfiles are in primary node right now. 

2.To distribute the work across all nodes we need to use `RemoteProcessorGroup(RPG)` and if we won't use RPG then all work is done by **`primary node only`** even you are running `Fetch` processors on all nodes.

3. By using **`RPG`** we are distributing the work across the cluster and if you increase `Concurrent Task` then we are going to get max performance out of NiFi cluster.

Comment: i have 3 node nifi cluster(say A,B,C), with B as primary. Configured RPG with https://A:8080/nifi, ListFile as primary and FetchFile as 'All nodes'. When I run, I'm only getting data from any one node. I.e. I run for 1st time, data is read from A, 2nd run data is read from B, 3rd run data is read from C. Every time I start and stop the flow. Is this the way it should work?

Comment: @srikanth, Yes, that's expected behavior from `RPG`. Even though you have configured RPG with `A node details` still RPG will distribute the work to all the nodes in the cluster based on `how much load on each node at the time and distribute the load dynamically`. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16120/how-do-i-distribute-data-across-a-nifi-cluster.html